# Rasa FormAction doens't get the values

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I have been working with rasa, and there are things of the `formAction` that I still do not understand very well, my question today is why? my `formAction` is activated but it does not store any `slotvalue`, if I am using it incorrectly? 
Here's my code:

```
class HotelForm(FormAction):
  def name(self):
    # type: () -> Text
    return "formaejemplo"

  @staticmethod
  def required_slots(tracker):
    return ["tipo_habitacion"]

  def slot_mappings(self):
    return {'tipo_habitacion':[self.from_entity(entity='tipo_habitacion',intent=['gethabitacion','peticion_habitacion'])]}

  @staticmethod
  def habitaciones_db():
    return ["individual","doble","suite","suite doble"]

  def submit(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
    dispatcher.utter_template('utter_listo', tracker)
    return []


  def validate(self,dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,tracker: Tracker,domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict]:
    slot_values = self.extract_other_slots(dispatcher, tracker, domain)
    print('slot values:',slot_values)
    slot_to_fill = tracker.get_slot(REQUESTED_SLOT)
    if slot_to_fill:
        print('slot values:',slot_values)
        slot_values.update(self.extract_requested_slot(dispatcher,tracker, domain))

    if not slot_values:
        try:
            return super().validate(dispatcher, tracker, domain)
        except ActionExecutionRejection as e:
            # could not extract entity
            dispatcher.utter_message(
                "Sorry, I could not parse the value correctly. \n"
                "Please double check your entry otherwise I will ask you this forever"
            )
            return []

    for slot, value in slot_values.items():
      print('Slot: ',slot)
      print('valor: ',values)
      if slot == 'tipo_habitacion':
        if value.lower() not in self.habitaciones_db():
          dispatcher.utter_template('utter_wrong_tipo_habitacion', tracker)
          # validation failed, set slot to None
          slot_values[slot] = None     

    # validation succeed, set the slots values to the extracted values
    return [SlotSet(slot, value) for slot, value in slot_values.items()]
```

---

when i print the values (`slotvalues`) on the console it always empty.

Answer (score 0):

when you  `print('slot values:',slot_values)` the first time, it's only collected extra slots (entities for required slots that it didn't ask for, but picked up anyway). You shouldn't have any of these since you only have one required slot.

As for the second time you `print('slot values:',slot_values)`, you're doing it before `slot_values.update(self.extract_requested_slot(dispatcher,tracker, domain))`, so it's exactly the same values as before. Try printing it after the updating happens. If you didn't run into the `if not slot_values` logic, then it should correctly print if you move it to after the update.

Did it correctly print when you did these lines?

```
      print('Slot: ',slot)
      print('valor: ',values)
```